# Redraw page border on scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, border, redraw

My webpage content is centered in the middle using auto margin and has a black border on both sides (left and right).

If I scroll down, the border doesn't update. So if I scroll down a bit the border will only reach half way down. How do i fix this?

Edit: The height of the content div is set to 100% and on initial load the border does go all the way down, this problem only occurs when scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The height of the content div is set to 100%

This is likely your problem. Because you've set the div to `height: 100%` it's only as tall as the viewport. (Even though the content overflows out of it.)

Try: `min-height: 100%`