# page not redrawing on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I shrink the width of my browser window (Firefox v26) so that only 1/2 of my home page is shown, the horizontal scrollbar appears on the bottom of the browser, which is fine.

But if I scroll the page to see its right half -- that right half is blank.  In other words, after horizontally scrolling to the right (which moves the page's content leftward, obviously) -- the right side of the page *does not redraw.*   It stays blank.  Even if I hit the refresh on the browser URL bar.

I looked around and saw several posts.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059757/redraw-page-border-on-scroll) seemed to be *exactly* the same problem (only difference was, theirs involved the *vertical* scrollbar).

So I took the suggestion there -- which was to set my outermost content div (called **wholePageDiv** in the code below) and also my **outerDiv** to 'min-width: 100%"  but this changed nothing.

Here's the very simple code:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <div id="wholePageDiv" class="wholePageDivForCentering"> 
      <div id="outerDiv" style="margin: 0; margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%; 
              display: inline-block; overflow: hidden">

          (not shown:  a bunch of divs with text)
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 <html>
```

Here is the **wholePageDivForCentering** CSS class, with the change made per that SO post I read:

```
  .wholePageDivForCentering
   {
      /* width: 100%; */
      min-width: 100%;
      /* height: 100%; */
      min-height: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

I have looked at other websites to see if they exhibit the same "right side of scrolled page does not redraw" problem.  On other websites I tested, I shrink the browser to 1/2 the width needed to show the whole page, then I scroll to see the right 1/2 of the page -- all other websites I check are successfully redrawing the right-side content as I scroll.

Do I have a CSS style problem above?

EDIT:  I hit F12 in my browser and use the 'Inspector' tool and I clearly see that the only visible content is within the **wholePageDiv** and this div is **not** expanding at all, to the right, as I scroll to the right -- the Inspector shows that for whatever reason my outermost **wholePageDiv** is remaining the same fixed size as the viewport, and when I scroll to the right, this viewport outline as shown by the Inspector simply shifts leftward and does not expand on the right side to accommodate moving the scrollbar to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this (for now) by either hard-coding the div's width, or by programmatically increasing the div's width as the width of the browser window/document was changed.  Hopefully will find a less kludgy solution later.

Answer (score 0):

I have added your html and css in a fiddle and it scrolls fine for me. The text of the div is displayed with no issues: http://jsfiddle.net/micahSan/UucLB/3/

```
same code as the OP
```

Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle so we can all see it?

Comment: In drilling down on this, I believe the problem is the content on the right side of my page, being a google map api's map, is the source of the trouble.  I'm digging into the google map api to see if I can make sense of why the map doesn't seem to 'realize' that as I scroll to the right, more of it is being exposed.  I found an app that has the exact same problem -- I suspect the owner may not realize it -- see padmapper.com -- max reduce his window width, scroll to the right, you see his app has the same white column, map not redrawing on the right side.  This may be a google maps bug.